# SFTP RSA authentication in Azure VM

Tags: linux, azure, cygwin, sftp, azure-virtual-machine

Requirement- Connecting SFTP server from local windows machines using WinSCP with keys

Technical- I have Azure VM(Windows 2012 server R2) in which Cygwin64 is installed for SFTP. 
I want to connect SFTP server using RSA authentication i.e using keys.

I have edited the sshd_config file for RSA authentication. In cygwin64 folder I have  also created .ssh folder and under that Authorized_keys file.

From local machine using putty I have generated Public and private keys and this public key I have entered in Authorized keys file but when I am trying to connect with that Private key it is saying "Server refused our key"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have entered in Authorized keys file but when I am trying to connect
>   with that Private key it is saying "Server refused our key"

If you see this type of message, the first thing you should do is check your server configuration carefully. Common errors include having the **wrong permissions or ownership set** on the public key or **the user’s home directory** on the server.

Maybe you can follow those steps to setup CYGWIN authenticate with private key:
1.**Install** GYCWIN (OpenSSH and cygrunsrv)
2.**configure** sshd use this command `ssh-host-config -y`
3.**Start** SSHD service with this command `cygrunsrv --start sshd`
4.Add your **public key** to `authorized_keys`(we can copy public Key to this file):

```
jason@jasonvm ~/.ssh
$ ls -a
.  ..  authorized_keys  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  id_rsa1  known_hosts
$ cat authorized_keys 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nxxx.......xxxxzaAVbeVFw==
jason@jasonvm ~/.ssh
$ pwd
/home/jason/.ssh
```

By the way, if you **can't** find this directory, you can use `ssh-keygen.exe` command to **create** this directory **/home/user/.ssh**, if you can't find this file `authorized_keys`, we should create it, and run this command `chmod 600 authorized_keys`

Afther that, we can use other Linux VM to SSH or SFTP this VM(we should open port 22 on Azure NSG inbound rules).
If you want to use winscp to login this VM, we should convert private key to `.ppk`. In this way, we can use this key to login this SFTP.

Note:
we can use winscp to convert `.key` to `.ppk`.[image]

For test, you may try to use Putty to login azure vm with your private key, to make sure you are using the right private key and public key.

**Update**:
We can add open ssh and sftp like this:[image][image][image]

Comment: No, it is still giving same problem "Server refused our key" from WinSCP I changed authorized keys with 600 mode but still not working.

Comment: can you use putty to login this vm use this private key

Comment: Actually that VM is Windows server 2012. I am installing SFTP on this.

Comment: I see, do you mean you just install cygrunsrv and not install openssh on it? openssh and cygrunsrv (SFTP)all the features of cygwin.

Comment: which version of cygwin your installed, would you add openssh to this VM? or can you re-install cygwin on this VM?

Comment: @Abhishekkumar after install OpenSSH and start it, we can use putty to login this VM use SSH.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: From password authentication it is working but with keys it is giving same error. I am planning to use with password authentication only. With WinSCP & FileZilla password authentication is working fine but with BizLink tool it is not getting connected neither with password nor with Keys.

Comment: I am marking this as answer because from your mentioned steps others can also create SFTP.