# SSH connect from local windows VM to Azure windows VM

Tags: windows, azure, ssh, openssh

I want to have a SSH connection from my local windows machine or VM on my computer to Azure windows server VM. I tried Cygwin and Putty but both of them gave timeout connection. I used public ip address and opened port 22 on Azure VM.
I will appreciate if some one can give me any hints or links.

Comment: According to your description, we can install **GYCWIN** on your Azure windows server vm, in this way, we can use putty to connect to this VM. Here a similar case, please refer to [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44188790/sftp-rsa-authentication-in-azure-vm/44193637#44193637).

Comment: @ Jason Ye - MSFT, I installed Cygwin on both machine and Putty on Host but still Putty gives Network error. Connection timed out. cygrunsrv --start sshd works on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for suggestions, I found the problem which was the host machine IP address(ipconfig) (where is a local VM inside domain) was different from the IP address that communicate outside the domain to internet. I was set in NSG of Azure VM to only accept this IP and because of that it gave time-out error. After changing the IP it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple firewalls that can be the reason here. Fist you must have a rule on the server to allow incoming SSH requests (port 22). Then you need to configure the NSG(Network security group) to allow incoming on port 22. If it still doesn't work, you need to verify that you are allowed to do an outgoing SSH request from your computer.